# missing package libraries in Yocto1.7

Tags: arm, embedded-linux, yocto

We have migrated code from Yocto1.5 to 1.7 and it seems with using the same configuration file(local.conf), I found that a lot of libraries previously installed on the 1.5 image(fsl-image-gui) was not present in the 1.7 image(core-image-sato)

I have manually added most of the packages except for two

```
libbeecrypt_cxx.so
liblcms.so(cmsutil)
```

I have already put in the code below and libbreecrypt was insalled but not libbeecrypt_cxx

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += beecrypt
```

I have not found a recipe/package for cmsutil. Anyone information regarding these would be appreciated.

Best Regards

Yuri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, regarding the beecrypt part of your question. Shortly after the 1.5 release, building the c++ bindings were made optional, and defaults to off.

See [patch making c++ optional](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/commit/meta/recipes-support/beecrypt/beecrypt_4.2.1.bb?id=e6885069e2af833ebacfd33a04147b095af92d20)

Thus, what you need is to add a `beecrypt_4.2.1.bbappend` file in your own layer which includes

```
PACKAGECONFIG += "cplusplus"
```

That the best, longterm solution. You could also set

```
PACKAGECONFIG_pn-beecrypt_append = "cplusplus"
```

in your `conf/local.conf`.

Comment: It seems somehow adding [PACKAGECONFIG += "cplusplus"] to the project added the other library packages as well.

Comment: Good; then it looks like beecrypt also build the second library.